# About choosing object relational mapping framework in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, object-relational-model

I am currently creating a some DAO in Java. But the application is not very large, so I am not consider to use hibernate or JPA. What light-weight framework can I use??
Thank :D

Comment: "lightweight" means nothing. Does it mean "easy to use"? "light on memory"? "light on processor"? "light on configuration"? The different kinds of "lightness" are exlusive. For example JPA is "light" as in "easy to use and set up". Hibernate and JPA is not an alternative (JPA is a standard, Hibernate is one of its implementations). Fix the question.

Comment: Sorry,, I should say if I dont want to use Javaee. as I know JPA need javaee right??

Comment: @JeffLee: no. JPA can be used outside of a Java EE container.

Comment: If i am only looking for the function that the data bind between the table and object. is there any franework to do this

Comment: But i need the javax.persistence library. I just download it and import to the build path????

Comment: Choose an implementation (EclipseLink, Hibernate, ...) and read its documentation on how to install and use.

Answer (score 2):

Neither Hibernate nor JPA would be what I would call "lightweight".

I'd recommend Spring JDBC template or iBatis.   Or just straight JDBC.  How hard can it be?

If you don't have a solid object model, no ORM solution will help you.  The "O" stands for "object".

If you know SQL well and want to think in terms of relations, I'd say that ORM is a bad choice.

Comment: Counting in "number of lines the programmer needs to write and maintain" Hibernate or other JPA library is extremaly light.

Comment: No, I don't believe that's true.  And dependencies matter.  That's the killer.

Comment: @duffymo: It's not the question of "believing". It's the question of actually counting the lines. And dependencies matter - sometimes. And sometimes not.

Comment: You're only counting the lines that you wrote, not the ones written for you.  Dependencies can matter.  And if you don't have an object model, ORM isn't for you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ormLite](http://ormlite.com/).  It's intended to be a lightweight ORM tool, but if I'm completely honest, I'd take duffymo's advice an just go Spring JDBC.

Comment: I am very new,, I would like to ask ,, is Spring JDBC have any relation with SpringMVC??

Comment: It's the same general idea of scanning components for injection but obviously the annotations and functionality are different.  Take a look at this example http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-jdbc-tutorial-1.html

Comment: @JeffLee: Spring is the name of a well-known framework. Spring JDBC is a couple (about 20) of classes that help with some common JDBC tasks (but do not map classes to tables) and are commonly used with Spring, but have no dependency on Spring itslef (there is no "scannning for components" or "injection" involved). SpringMVC is a complicated, legacy web framework built with Spring.

Comment: Yes, Spring is a large framework with MVC and persistence, among other things, but you don't have to use all of it if you choose not to.  Focus on what you need and grow it out.

Answer (score 0):

The lightest solution - in terms of setup - would be Eclipselink (which is a JPA implementation). Using Hibernate would yield identical code (because it is a JPA implementation too), but would require more dependencies.

To use Eclipselink you just need three jars in your classpath and a very short configuration file (META-INF/persistence.xml). The simplest way to see which jars exactly would be to use Netbeans and add them using *libraries->add->eclipselink (jpa 2.1)*.

No matter which solution you choose you also need a relevant JDBC driver.

If you are a beginner, a JPA library (like Eclipselink or Hibernate JPA) is a good choice because:

- your IDE will probably have some tooling to help you with persistence.xml and mapping;
- it is a very popular standard and programmers generally agree that it's good;
- it let's you do simple things very easily; bootstrapping is one line of code, configuring a simple class can be done in just two annotations;
- it let's you grow: when you want to use Java EE stack one day, it will be good to know JPA.